# Validating the values in a range of rows and columns and updating some values on it

Tags: excel, vba

How can you make VBA validate the values you have in a range or column?

For example you have the range from A1 - A10 with values:

cat, cat, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, cat, cat, dog.

So it looks like this in excel:
[image]

Now the logic I would want this to have is that, when there are three consecutive dogs, the third dog becomes a mouse, when the previous one is a mouse the next then will be updated to cow. etc2. I have this logic no matter what the arrangement or patter on the 10 cells. So basically it would show like this after:
[image]

anyone who has an idea on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What code have you tried and what problem did you have with it?

Comment: @braX: what I have tried is manually changing the values thru vba, like the range from A1:A10 then on A5 i manually update it to mouse, i want it to go like even thought the patter is scrambled the logic still applies and not how my code did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do.

Create an array: `Dim varData(1 To 10) As Variant`

Then, assign the values to positions in the array.

`varData(1) = Cells(2,1)`
`varData(2) = Cells(2,2)` 
Keep on going until you hit the last value. You could do this in a for loop if you would like.

Then, do an If statement inside a for loop:

```
For i = 1 to 10
   If varData(i) = "dog" Then
       counter = counter + 1
       If counter = 3 Then
          varData(i) = "Mouse"
          Cells(2,i) = "Mouse"
       End If
       If varData(i-1) = "Mouse" Then
          varData(i) = "Cow"
          Cells(2,i) = "Cow"
   Else
       counter = 0
   End If
Next i
```

Hope this helps. Ask if you need any questions.

**A comment asked for an addition of code**

Use the RND function as found [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php)

Something like: '''    testNum = int(Rnd(1))   '''' This will give you a number between 0 and 1.

Then use if else statements...

```
For i = 1 to 10
    If testNum = 0 Then
        Cells(2,i) = "Dog"
    Else
        Cells(2,i) = "Cat"
    If varData(i) = "dog" Then
       counter = counter + 1
       If counter = 3 Then
          varData(i) = "Mouse"
          Cells(2,i) = "Mouse"
       End If
       If varData(i-1) = "Mouse" Then
          varData(i) = "Cow"
          Cells(2,i) = "Cow"
   Else
       counter = 0
   End If
```

Im sure there is a better way to do it, but this is a basic idea.

WiebeCoding

Comment: Hey Man this actually works, although I do have one more questions, this validates given the value is already there but what if we go and be the one to provide the values following the rules?

Like generate these values in a range where there should be two consecutive dogs followed by a mouse then a cow?

Comment: You could do a random statement that has a random number being picked and then calling an array that has the values in it. The last number in the array would be the progression like ```dog, dog, mouse, cow```. That is the way I would do it

Comment: do you have any samples of that code man? I cant seem to get a grasp on it.

Comment: @Link Before I answer you question, are you asking how to put the values in the table in the order that is shown in img 2 or are your asking how to based off of random numbers to create a random arrangement of of dogs and cat and then going back through it to find the triple dogs? This will make sure that I answer your question correctly.

Comment: it's the second one.

Comment: @Link I have update by answer to give you an idea